# New row in model doesn't persist in QDataWidgetMapper when QFileDialog is called

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a simple form where I have a function/method which calls a QFileDialog to choose a file.  This form stores the information in a Postgresql database and uses QDataWidgetMapper to map the form fields to database fields.  When I add a new row to the model and edit some fields, when I call the QFileDialog, it seems the mappings get removed. All the edited fields on the form go blank. If I go back to a record which was retrieved from the database, I have no problems adding the image as the data persists on the form.

It seems to be related to the `submit = self.c_mapper.submit()` line of code. When I comment this out, the data persists in the form but I also can’t get the query().LastInsertId().

When stepping through the code, the form field data disappears when `if dlg.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:` line is reached.

The desired behaviour is to be able to call the function which selects the image file and continue editing the same record with the correct data in the fields.

See the animation:
[image: Animation of QdataWidgetMapper problem]

See the code:

```
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

#PyQt stuff
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

#form modules
from form import *


class Contact(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, cont_id,  parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.cont_id = cont_id
        self.ui = Ui_contact_form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
 
        self.c_model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.c_model.setTable("contacts")
        self.c_model.select()

        self.row = self.c_model.rowCount()
        self.c_model.insertRow(self.row)
        self.setWindowTitle('New contact')
            
        self.c_mapper = QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.c_mapper.setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper.ManualSubmit)
        self.c_mapper.setModel(self.c_model)
        #self.c_mapper.setItemDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate(self))
        self.c_mapper.addMapping(self.ui.title, self.c_model.fieldIndex("title"))
        self.c_mapper.addMapping(self.ui.first_name, self.c_model.fieldIndex("first_name"))       
        self.c_mapper.addMapping(self.ui.last_name, self.c_model.fieldIndex("last_name"))
        self.c_mapper.addMapping(self.ui.nickname, self.c_model.fieldIndex("nickname"))       
        self.c_mapper.addMapping(self.ui.job_title, self.c_model.fieldIndex("job_title"))       
        self.c_mapper.addMapping(self.ui.birth_date, self.c_model.fieldIndex("birth_date"))
        self.c_mapper.addMapping(self.ui.website, self.c_model.fieldIndex("website"))
        self.c_mapper.addMapping(self.ui.comments, self.c_model.fieldIndex("comments"))
        self.c_mapper.addMapping(self.ui.users, self.c_model.fieldIndex("user_name"))
        self.c_mapper.addMapping(self.ui.tags, self.c_model.fieldIndex("tags"))
        self.c_mapper.setCurrentIndex(self.row)

        self.ui.get_image_file.clicked.connect(self.get_profile_image)

    def get_profile_image(self):
        submit = self.c_mapper.submit()
        self.cont_id = self.c_model.query().lastInsertId()
        data_loc = Path('/home/dave/hd/Nextcloud/crm_data/')
        database = 'crm'

        dlg = QFileDialog(self)
        dlg.setFileMode(QFileDialog.AnyFile)
        home = os.path.expanduser('~') + "/Downloads"
        dlg.setDirectory(home)
        if dlg.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            selected_file = dlg.selectedFiles()[0]
        else:
            return

        selected_file = Path(selected_file)
        ext = selected_file.suffix
        ext = ext.lower()
        target_loc = data_loc / database / "contacts/images"
        target_file = str(self.cont_id) + ext
        target_dest = target_loc / target_file
        shutil.move(str(selected_file), str(target_dest))
        self.ui.image.setPixmap(QPixmap(str(target_dest)).scaled(self.ui.image.size(),Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

        
if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db.setHostName('hostname')
    db.setDatabaseName('crm')
    db.setUserName('usr')
    db.setPassword('pw')
    if (db.open()==False):
        QMessageBox.critical(None, "Database Error", db.lastError().text())

    myapp = Contact('')
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Well, for starters, I'd like to understand why you're using QSqlRelationalDelegate. Then, the problem is difficult to understand as we don't know the contents, layout or extent (row/column count) of your model, and then there's the issue that you're adding a new row in the `__init__` and submit it anyway, no matter if the data in the mapped fields have changed or not. I strongly suggest to take your time and provide us a [mre].

Comment: Sorry @musicamante. That is a relic from when I cut down the code to a minimal reproducible example. I have edited the code to comment that line. Thanks for pointing that out.

The code runs regardless of that error. The question still remains.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing that line doesn't make your code a [mre]. While we could *try* to make it reproducible, we might not be able to *actually* reproduce the issue, as we still don't know the db layout/setup. For instance, if the model has several hundreds of items it might behave in different ways. I suggest you again to do some efforts in crafting a proper MRE (maybe with a basic sqlite db): it has to be something *anybody* could easily copy, paste and run, without substantial modifications. For instance, the whole `get_profile_image` is pointless, if the problem comes just *after* that.

Comment: Please note: creating a proper MRE is not something you do in a few minutes. It can be very hard, it could take *hours*. But that's how it's expected to be (and how debugging is also expected to be, sometimes): reduce code to minimal parts, remove unimportant elements, ensure that the problem still happens; whether it does or not, then you've probably found the culprit, if you still don't understand it, then you can ask a more specific question we can work with (it's reproducible), but you should also take the next step by removing all *other* non-essential parts to make it actually *minimal*.